# python setuptools setup.cfg: Including main- and subpackages in the build dir

Tags: python, setuptools

I would like to create a pip package for my python software using a [setup.cfg](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html) file. My program is currently structured as following:

```
mypkg
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    ├── subpkg
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── file_1.py
    ...
```

so far, using the setuptools `find_packages()` function allowed me to add my main package as well as the subpackage to my build package. When using a `setup.cfg` file however, I am not able to include both in my package anymore. The [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages)  shows that subpackages can be included by adding the option

```
[options]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =src

[options.packages.find]
where = src
include = *
```

But this only includes the subpackage files and not the main package files in my case. Is there a way for me to include all my files while still making use of a setup.cfg setup file?

Comment: What do you want the top-level importable packages and/or modules to be? In other words, what should a user of you library type to import your library in their code (`import xxx`)? -- Seems like in your case you need to add an additional directory layer right under `src`. In other words your actual Python code should be all placed under `src/mypkg`.

Comment: Rephrasing @sinoroc's question: what is the purpose of the `src/__init__.py` file?

Answer (score 4):

Using the directory layout in your example, I found a couple configurations that worked. Both of these allowed me to import all modules from the `src` package and `src.subpkg`.

```
[options]
packages=find:
```

and the other doesn't use the `find:`  feature at all.

```
[options]
packages =
    src
    src.subpkg
```

According to the setuptools documentation
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

> If your packages are not in the root of the repository you also need to configure package_dir:

And since the `src` package is located in the root of the repository specifying a `package_dir` is not necessary.

This actually works similarly to `find_packages` function inside a `setup.py` file.  When called with no arguments, `find_packages()` in a project, it finds all of your top-level and sub-packages automatically.